# convert simple curl data request to powershell invoke-webrequest

Tags: json, powershell, curl

Converting a very simple Plaid API curl data request to a powershell invoke-webrequest

what works:

```
    curl -X POST https://tartan.plaid.com/balance \
  -d client_id=client-id-value \
  -d secret=secret-value \
  -d access_token=access-token-value
```

What I'm trying unsuccessfully in Powershell

```
#test powershell api call

$hash = @{  client_id    = "client-id-value";
            secret = "secret-value"
            access_token = "access-token-value"
            }

$JSON = $hash | convertto-json

#Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://tartan.plaid.com/balance" -Method POST -Body $JSON
```

This returns a plaid error 1100 (client id missing), so I know some API functionality is working, but it's not parsing input data correctly.

My biggest misunderstanding is how to translate a "curl -data" value into the proper Powershell parameter.

Is this a header value, body value? etc.

Comment: Skip the `convertto-json` step

Comment: Changing to the following appears to have worked, though I've learned my access token is expired.  
`$post_values = @{client_id='value';secret='value2';access_token='value3'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://tartan.plaid.com/balance -Method POST -Body $post_values`

Answer (score 1):

Unless the target url expects the POST body to be in JSON format, skip the `ConvertTo-JSON` step completely.

When the chosen HTTP method is `POST`, `Invoke-WebRequest` will automatically take all the keys in the hashtable supplied to the `-Body` parameter and construct a body payload similar to that of `curl -d`:

```
$POSTParams = @{
    client_id    = "client-id-value"
    secret       = "secret-value"
    access_token = "access-token-value"
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://tartan.plaid.com/balance" -Method POST -Body $POSTParams
```